# layout buttons size gets changed on vaadin dialog popup

Tags: java, dialog, vaadin

I am creating a dialog popup for a logout button, but whenever I am clicking on my logout button, my other buttons layout changes.

Code for logout button:

```java
hl1=new HorizontalLayout();
hl1.setSizeFull();
hl1.setHeight("40px");
hl1.setMargin(false);
hl1.setPadding(false);
hl1.setSpacing(true);
logout = new Button("Logout");
logout.setAutofocus(isVisible());
hl1.add(l2,logout);
```

Code for dialog:

```java
logout.addClickListener(new ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>>() {
    public void onComponentEvent(ClickEvent<Button> event) {
        logout();
    }

    protected void logout() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.setModal(false);
        dialog.setDraggable(true);
        UI.getCurrent().setChildComponentModal(dialog, false);
        dialog.setHeaderTitle("Do you really want to logout? You will loose unsaved work");

        VerticalLayout dialogLayout = createDialogLayout();
        dialog.add(dialogLayout);

        Button YesButton = createYesButton(dialog);
        Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel", e -> dialog.close());
        dialog.getFooter().add(cancelButton);
        dialog.getFooter().add(YesButton);
        dialog.addThemeVariants(DialogVariant.LUMO_NO_PADDING);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your `hl1` relate to your dialog? This code seems unrelated. You should post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry for the half code now you can check this i ll update my code

Comment: What “other buttons”? And how exactly does their layout change?

Comment: Maybe you can add some "before" and "after" screenshots?

Comment: other buttons size is going to increase whenever i click on the logout button